# How to let the embedded object use its natural size?

Tags: html

I'm using `<object>` to embed an SWF file like this:

```
<object width="900" height="900">
    <param name="movie" value="carte-uso-ch-01.swf">
</object>
```

I don't know if this is portable and it really doesn't matter here, this is just for personal use. Is there any way to let the SWF expand to its actual size, instead of restricting it to 900x900? If I remove the `width` and `height` attributes from `<object>` I'll only get a thumb displayed.

Comment: I _think_ you can use `style="min-height:900px;min-width:900px;"` instead of using static sizes (though I'm not positive on an `<object>`)

Comment: @Brad It produces the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP running, you can use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on SWF files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<object width="100%" height="100%">
```

or JavaScript `width` and`height` detection